# How to fade out one image by clicking it and bring in another image in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I wanted to make an app in android studio. It shows the image of Bart Simpson at launch. If I click the image then it will fade out in 2 seconds and image of Homer Simpson will appear. This is what I tried:

XML:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bartImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bart_simspon" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

java code:-

```
package com.example.animations;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView bartImageView;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bartImageView=findViewById(R.id.bartImageView);
        bartImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bartImageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
                bartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homer_simpson);
            }
        });


}
}
```

But if I run the app on my phone what is happening is that the image of Homer Simpson is appearing and fading after 2 sec.

Why is this happening?

If we go programmatically then ideally the image of Bart Simpson should fade out and Homer Simpson should appear.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to set your alpha to 1 after the animation

```
bartImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bartImageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        bartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homer_simpson);
                        bartImageView.setAlpha(1f);
                    }
                });;


            }


        });
```

Comment: If I didn't put `bartImageView.setAlpha(1f);`, what would be the default alpha value?

Comment: 0 which is what you set in your animation  and hence it will not be visible

Answer (score 0):

you can set listener for animation and when finish animation change image resource

```
bartImageView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                  bartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homer_simpson);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: In my code, why is "bartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homer_simpson);" getting executed first then "bartImageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);" is getting executed?

Comment: you set in `xml android:src="@drawable/bart_simspon"`

Comment: you init view in xml  with bart_simspon

Comment: My question is why `bartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homer_simpson);` getting executed first instead of `bartImageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);` when I wrote that first?  I set `xml android:src="@drawable/bart_simspon` because I want to show that image initially

Comment: you wrong, `bartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homer_simpson)` did not execut befor that that seams because you init imageview in xml